# Using DexGuard to obfuscate dynamically loaded classes

Tags: java, android, proguard, dexguard

I'm working to get classes loaded dynamically view `DexClassLoader` in Android. I've managed to get it done but I need these dynamically loaded classes to be obfuscated for security. Is there anyway to do it with DexGuard/ProGuard or some other tools?

Answer (score 0):

You will dynamically load a DEX file that contains your Class(s), so you have first to create it by compiling the final APK and extract it. Building the APK allows obfuscation and shrinking, so you have just to enable them in the Gradle file before build the APK.

Then you will use the DexClassLoader to load the DEX file.